# Is Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) Supported on Windows IoT Core

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot, ndis, wfp

I have not been able to locate documentation indicating whether Windows 10 IoT Core supports WFP in any capacity. I am particularly interested in whether IoT Core supports WFP callout drivers.

[Background on WFP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to run the WFP sample on Windows IoT Core. It includes a driver project named **WFPSamplerCalloutDriver**. Since the the target of projectis for Windows Desktop, it may show error when compiling for Windows IoT Core. You need to change the [DriverTargetPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/windows-10-editions-for-universal-drivers) to **Universal** which supports Windows IoT Core.

[Windows Filtering Platform Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/6c1981b8504329521343ad00f32daa847fa6083a/network/trans/WFPSampler)

**Update:**
I have compiled the WFPSamplerCalloutDriver sample for Windows IoT Core successfully, and built/installed the driver package on my device(Raspberry PI) with no errors. But I can not find the installed drivers via command `devcon driverfiles *` after booting the device.

Comment: @DaveRuske, sorry for my mistake. I updated the response.

Comment: I've had no success getting that sample's callout driver installed on IoT Core yet, either, though the sample works fine on Desktop. Manually installing the callout driver with devcon gives me a node at root\devcon\0000. Initially this has a problem code of 1 (CM_PROB_NOT_CONFIGURED); after reboot, it is 28 (CM_PROB_FAILED_INSTALL). I'll keep picking away at it.

Comment: @DaveRuske, how did you install the driver on IoT Core? Did you create a driver package(*.cab) file adn then applyupdate the cab file on device?

Comment: Ultimately the callout driver would be built into the custom IoT image for the device, but for test purposes I copied the inf, cat, and sys files to the device, then used Powershell to execute "devcon install wpfsamplercalloutdriver.inf WPFCALLOUTS". I have some experience with KMDF kernel drivers on desktop platforms, but the IoT particulars are new to me, so this may be an entirely invalid approach.

Comment: @DaveRuske, `devcon install` will not install the driver successfully on IoT Core. You need to refer to this [docuement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/driverdeployment) to deploy the driver on IoT Core. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/add-a-driver-to-an-image#build-a-package-for-your-driver) shows how to create a package for a driver on IoT Core.